# How to auth users with JWT in django microservice-like project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I already have JWT from external auth service and want to use it in my django (DRF actually) project, I also want to populate user model basing on this jwt. How can I implement this? most of libs are about django as auth service, not just client

Comment: have you looked at this module? https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy try this repo